# TinyTDS error when using uniq function in has_many, through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, tiny-tds

I am currently running:

```
Windows 7 64-bit
Rails 4.1.1
Ruby 2.0.0p481
tiny_tds [gem] 0.6.2
```

I have successfully started a rails application to access a remote SQL Server (I'm not sure what the version of the server is). I have a model, `resource.rb`, with the following association:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'tResources'
    self.primary_key = 'emp_Id'

    has_many :project_resources, foreign_key: 'emp_Id'
    has_many :projects, through: :project_resources
    ...

    default_scope { order("#{Resource.table_name}.lastname ASC") }
    ...
```

The model `project_resource.rb` has the following:

```
class ProjectResource < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'tProject_Resources'
    self.primary_key = 'key_Id'

    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :resource, foreign_key: 'emp_Id'
    belongs_to :calendar
    ...
```

This all works great. If I have a resource, `r`, I can get all the projects associated with `r` by referencing `r.projects`. However, there are some duplicate projects in this association, so in my view, I'm currently successfully using `r.projects.uniq`.

I want to move the `uniq` to the `has_many` as follows:

```
has_many :projects, -> { uniq }, through: :project_resources
```

With the association defined this way, the only reference to `r.projects` that I've tried which succeeds is: `r.projects.count` which does give me an accurate count of unique projects for resource `r`.

However, other references, such as simply `r.projects`, yields an TinyTDS error:

```
irb(main):010:0> r.projects
  Project Load (290.0ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT *, __order FROM (
 SELECT [tProjects].*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC) AS __order, ROW_NUM
BER() OVER (PARTITION BY [tProjects].* ORDER BY name ASC) AS __joined_row_num FR
OM [tProjects] INNER JOIN [tProject_Resources] ON [tProjects].[project_Id] = [tP
roject_Resources].[project_id] WHERE [tProject_Resources].[emp_Id] = @0 ) AS __s
q WHERE __joined_row_num = 1 ORDER BY __order', N'@0 int', @0 = 471  [["emp_Id",
 471]]
TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near '*'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT
 *, __order FROM ( SELECT [tProjects].*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC) A
S __order, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [tProjects].* ORDER BY name ASC) AS _
_joined_row_num FROM [tProjects] INNER JOIN [tProject_Resources] ON [tProjects].
[project_Id] = [tProject_Resources].[project_id] WHERE [tProject_Resources].[emp
_Id] = @0 ) AS __sq WHERE __joined_row_num = 1 ORDER BY __order', N'@0 int', @0
= 471
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near '*'.: EXEC
 sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT *, __order FROM ( SELECT [tProjects].*, DENSE_R
ANK() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC) AS __order, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [tPro
jects].* ORDER BY name ASC) AS __joined_row_num FROM [tProjects] INNER JOIN [tPr
oject_Resources] ON [tProjects].[project_Id] = [tProject_Resources].[project_id]
 WHERE [tProject_Resources].[emp_Id] = @0 ) AS __sq WHERE __joined_row_num = 1 O
RDER BY __order', N'@0 int', @0 = 471
```

I'm looking for some guidance as to why this error is occurring. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This line has a problem

```
PARTITION BY [tProjects].*
```

I would expect a specific column here.

I have the similar setups on my PC but could not duplicate your problem in rails console. `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0)` `tiny_tds (0.6.2)` `rails (4.1.1)` `activerecord (4.1.1, 4.0.3)`.

Here is my outputs:

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
2.1.0 :001 > require 'LvQaOrderService'
 => true
2.1.0 :002 > p = Product.where(id: 36860201)  
SQL (282.9ms)  USE [order_service]  
Product Load (313.2ms)  
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [products].* FROM [products] WHERE [products].[id] = 36860201'
2.1.0 :003 > p.first.inventories
Inventory Load (343.9ms)  
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT [inventory].* FROM [inventory] INNER JOIN [product_inventory] ON [inventory].[id] = [product_inventory].[inventory_id] WHERE [product_inventory].[product_id] = @0', N'@0 bigint', @0 = 36860201`
```

Here is my setup:

```
#product.rb
class Product < LvQaOrderService
has_many :product_inventories
has_many :inventories, -> { uniq }, :through => :product_inventories
end

#product_inventory.rb
class ProductInventory < LvQaOrderService
self.table_name = "product_inventory" 

belongs_to :product
belongs_to :inventory
end

#inventory.rb
class Inventory < LvQaOrderService
self.table_name = "inventory" 

has_many :product_inventories
has_many :products, :through => :product_inventories
end
```

Comment: The problem is that my code doesn't create that line directly. Either Rails and/or tiny_tds does. So I'm wondering if there's a bug in the tiny_tds gem in this scenario.

Comment: And what's your gem version for `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`?

Comment: My `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gem version is 4.1.0.

Comment: @luker I updated my answer with more info. Hope it helps. In my case, I could not duplicate it. Weird. Could you show more info about your setups?

Comment: In my original problem statement, I have added a bit more info that I use in the models. The tables are external to me so I don't control their key structure. They are not using Rails standard naming, so I am setting the table name and primary key explicitly, and using `foreign_key` where needed. I also have a `default_scope` for resources. There are associations with other tables in the models which I don't think come to bear on the problem. Let me know if you want to know anything else.